# Why did WWIII happen because of the explosion?

Tags: akira

Alright, so in AKIRA the big psychic explosion causes WW3. My question is: why did WW3 ensue afterwards? Did the Japanese government cover it up as a nuclear explosion? It seems counterintuitive to start WW3, even if it is to cover up your psychic program.

Comment: Someone might come up with a good, sensible reason, but my default explanation for anything in the Akira movie is that the story just makes no sense.

Comment: You can't be sure to 100% the ww3 starting wa just a key element to getting a decent story going, there are probably multiple reasons that we don't know about in which the countries were wanting an excuse to go to war for.